# Cut specific columns and collapse with delimiter in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, cut

Say I have 6 different columns in a text file (as shown below)

```
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1
1   G   PP  GG  HH  GG
z   T   CC  GG  FF  JJ
```

I would like to extract columns first, second and fourth columns as A1_B1_D1 collapsed together and the third column separated by tab.

So the result would be:

```
A1_B1_D1    C1  
1_G_GG      PP
z_T_GG      CC
```

I tried

`cut -f 1,2,4 -d$'\t' 3`, but is just not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
{
  print $1"_"$2"_"$4,$3
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to maintain your column alignment, you can check the length of the combination of fields 1, 2 and 4 and add one or two `tab` characters as necessary,

```
awk '{
    printf (length($1"_"$2"_"$4) >= 8) ? "%s_%s_%s\t%s\n" : "%s_%s_%s\t\t%s\n",
            $1,$2,$4,$3
}' file
```

**Example Output**

```
A1_B1_D1        C1
1_G_GG          PP
z_T_GG          CC
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried RavinderSingh13 code and it has the same output as mine but I don't quite know the difference, anyways, here it is:

`awk -F ' ' '{print $1"_"$2"_"$4"\t"$3}' /path/to/file`

Comment: That's because I have set OFS value as tab and you are manually putting tab character between values in print.

Comment: @Augusto: OFS: The output field separator, a space by default.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+.*/\1_\2_\4\t\3/' -E file
```

Use pattern matching and back references.

`\S+` means one or more non-white space characters.

`\s+` means one or more white space characters.

`\t` represents a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk and using column -t for formatting.

```
$ cat cols_345.txt
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1
1   G   PP  GG  HH  GG
z   T   CC  GG  FF  JJ
$ awk -v OFS="_" '{ $3="\t"$3; print $1,$2,$4 $3 } ' cols_345.txt | column -t
A1_B1_D1  C1
1_G_GG    PP
z_T_GG    CC
$
```